# Using cron job + git to automatically backup live database

Tags: mysql, git, amazon-web-services, cron

Im hosting a web system on an Ubuntu instance on AWS. Its very critical that the database is backed up often. I've been looking at automated instance snapshots, but I do not find this solution desirable for two reasons: Its overkill to backup the entire instance, and all guides I've seen recommend only a single backup a day.

Im considering writing a small shell script that uses git to periodically commit changes in the MySQL database and push to a remote repo. The script should be activated by a cron job.

My question is: Will this approach work? I have not seen this solution proposed anywhere, so I suspect that I'm missing something here. 
The database will never be larger than 50 mb.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work - I have used something similar for a pet project of mine. Even the output of `mysqldump` is quite git-friendly, you can view diffs nicely etc.

It's not very common to use git for backups though, which is probably why you have not seen it proposed anywhere. There are solutions designed solely for backups which are preferable over git.

Comment: My concern is if changes are made to the database while the "git commit" is executing, then the commit will probably be corrupted. 
How big was the database and how much traffic did you have?
In my sitation the traffic is pretty  low (<1000 hits a day) and the size of the  database is also on the low end.

Comment: It is a very low traffic site, under 100 hits a day. In my setup, I execute `mysqldump <params> > database.sql` and then add the resulting sql file in git. mysqldump will not fail even if there's concurrent traffic.

Comment: Agreed, it can be done. According to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19532/safest-way-to-perform-mysqldump-on-a-live-system-with-active-reads-and-writes its safe to generate a sql dump on a system with active reads and writes. Thanks

Comment: I'd also mention that it helps passing `--skip-comments` and `--skip-dump-date` options to `mysqldump` to lower the amount of irrelevant differences between the dump file. Personally, I'm using `/usr/bin/mysqldump --force --opt --routines --skip-comments --skip-dump-date $dbname"`.